# gradle error - com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()Ljava/util/stream/Collector

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, gradle, guava, android-gradle-3.0

I've seen this mentioned a couple of times but yet to find a solution - after upgrading Gradle to 4.10.2 and the Android gradle plugin to 3.2.1, I'm having a lot of difficulties trying to build an Android app. It appears to be an incompatibility between plugins, specifically to do with the version of Guava in use.  I believe it's one of the AWS plugins I'm using that's causing the issue but I'm using the latest version and I can't find any straightforward way of separating out the gradle script that needs the AWS plugin and the one that needs the Android plugin.  Is there some way I can tell gradle which version of Guava to use when loading the AWS plugin?  I've tried this but to no avail:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android"
    classpath "jp.classmethod.aws:gradle-aws-plugin:0.38"
  }
}
```

Just removing that last classpath entry fixes the problem, but I need it for the AWS tasks.

The strange thing is after I get that error and run gradle again I get a completely different error: "Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder". This doesn't seem to get any google hits at all that are helpful.

FWIW the stack trace is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.DependenciesImpl.<init>(DependenciesImpl.java:97)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.<clinit>(ModelBuilder.java:134)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.registerModels(BasePlugin.java:612)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.configureExtension(BasePlugin.java:576)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.java:290)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AbstractAppPlugin.apply(AbstractAppPlugin.java:122)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.java:43)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.apply(AppPlugin.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:42)
 ...
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, for anyone wondering:
```configurations.classpath {
           resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working by adding this to the root build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force "com.google.guava:guava:23.0"
    force "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2"
    force "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"
  }
}
```

After resolving the first conflict with guava there were 2 further ones, hence the necessary extra lines.

App seems to build and run fine, and the AWS commands are executing OK.